# Generating attendance list for hours without a matching row

Tags: sqlite, null

I have a project that calculates work hour from the attendance logs that I import from attendance machine. I use SQLite database and VB .NET.

First I'll show the table that I use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [CheckLogs] (
[IDCheckLog] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
[IDEmployee] TEXT NOT NULL, 
[Dates] TEXT NOT NULL, 
[In] TEXT, 
[Out] TEXT, 
[OverTime] NUMERIC DEFAULT 0);

CREATE TABLE integers (i INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO integers (i) VALUES
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Table CheckLogs is the data that I import from the attendance machine. The OverTime column is calculated in my program. Table integer is used to create the date list, I got it from [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/returning-every-saturday-between-two-dates/2990/2).

I want to generate a view that shows employee attendance between 2 dates and display the CheckLogs data if the employee is present and null if absent. Because in the table CheckLogs, when the employee is absent then there is no data from that day from this employee.

This is the view that I desired (this is report for employee 10001 between 2014-10-01 and 2014-10-05):

```sql
Dates      | IDEmployee | In    | Out
---------------------------------------
2014-10-01 | 10001      | 07:00 | 16:00
2014-10-02 | 10001      | 07:01 | 15:58
2014-10-03 | 10001      | null  | null
2014-10-04 | 10001      | 07:08 | 15:48
2014-10-05 | 10001      | null  | null
```

And this is the query that I have now:

```sql
SELECT X.[Dates], C.[IDEmployee], C.[In], C.[Out]
FROM
(select date('2014-10-01', '+' || (H.i*100 + T.i*10 + U.i) || ' day') as Dates
  from integers as H
cross
  join integers as T
cross
  join integers as U
    where date('2005-01-25', '+' || (H.i*100 + T.i*10 + U.i) || ' day') <= '2014-10-05') AS X
    , CheckLogs AS C USING (Dates)
    WHERE C.[IDEmployee]='10001'
```

From this query I have this result:

```sql
Dates      | IDEmployee | In    | Out
---------------------------------------
2014-10-01 | 10001      | 07:00 | 16:00
2014-10-02 | 10001      | 07:01 | 15:58
2014-10-04 | 10001      | 07:08 | 15:48
```

Answer (score 0):

To get NULL values for rows without a match, you need an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join).
And you have to take care not to filter out those rows with a WHERE clause that would not match NULL values; to get dates that do not match a condition, you have to put *that* condition into the join's ON clause:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ( ... ) AS X
LEFT JOIN CheckLogs AS C ON C.Dates = X.Dates AND
                            C.IDEmployee = '10001'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted the wrong query, I've update the correct query. I already use LEFT JOIN, but the result doesn't have the NULL values. Thanks

Comment: Thank you CL, the WHERE clause is the cause of my problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a problem, if there is a match with other employee then the value for that date won't be displayed. For example, if IDEmployee 10002 not absent in 2014-10-03 then the query for IDEmployee 10001 won't have the 2014-10-03 row.